# Create two tables with REFERENCES

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

I'm reading a dbms book and I got this example of constraints:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Students (
    sid CHAR(20),
    name CHAR(20),
    login CHAR(20),
    age INTEGER,
    honors CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    gpa REAL,
    PRIMARY KEY (sid),
    FOREIGN KEY (honors) REFERENCES Courses(cid)
);

CREATE TABLE Courses (
    cid CHAR(10),
    cname CHAR(10),
    credits INTEGER,
    grader CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (cid),
    FOREIGN KEY (grader) REFERENCES Students(sid)
);
```

With this code I get an error everytime I try to create any of these two tables.

How do I make the FK constraints DEFERRED so I can create these tables?

Comment: [Don't use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Answer (score 0):

Forward references are not allowed for foreign key relationships.  So add the first one after the second table is created:

```
CREATE TABLE Students (
    sid CHAR(20),
    name CHAR(20),
    login CHAR(20),
    age INTEGER,
    honors CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    gpa REAL,
    PRIMARY KEY (sid)
 );

CREATE TABLE Courses (
    cid CHAR(10),
    cname CHAR(10),
    credits INTEGER,
    grader CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (cid),
    FOREIGN KEY (grader) REFERENCES Students(sid)
);

ALTER TABLE students ADD  FOREIGN KEY (honors) REFERENCES Courses(cid);
```

Note:  I strongly recommend that you use `VARCHAR()` for strings.  Usually you don't want to deal with trailing spaces.

Also, integer primary keys are often preferred (via a `generated always as identity` column).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified query for Foreign Key constraints

```
CREATE TABLE Students (
    sid CHAR(20),
    name CHAR(20),
    login CHAR(20),
    age INTEGER,
    honors CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    gpa REAL,
    PRIMARY KEY (sid),
);

CREATE TABLE Courses (
    cid CHAR(10),
    cname CHAR(10),
    credits INTEGER,
    grader CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (cid),
    FOREIGN KEY (grader) REFERENCES Students(sid)
);

ALTER TABLE Students ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (honors) REFERENCES Courses(cid)
```